# Why does the helper path for POST change when index is removed from routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Normally such a line in `routes.rb`

```
resources :tenants
```

generates the following routes (and a few more):

```
| tenants_path | GET  | /tenants(.:format) | tenants#index |
|              | POST | /tenants(.:format) | tenants#create |
```

However when I try to remove `index action` from `routes.rb` like this:

```
resources :tenants, except: :index
```

The Path/Url helper for `tenants#create` POST action is overridden and is given the `tenants_path`:

```
| tenants_path | POST | /tenants(.:format) | tenants#create |
```

Why does it happen and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path helper name is only shown for the first matching route in the generated `rails routes`. `tenants_path` will generate `example.com/tenants`. What REST method to use, e.g. `GET`, `POST` or something else Rails figures out on its own.

```
| tenants_path | GET |
|              | POST |
```

When you say `except: :index` is just means the first matching route is different, the generated path is still `example.com/tenants`

```
| tenants_path | POST |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resource :tenants
```

resources creates routes including index but resource does not,

see this
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: `resource :tenants` would provide some routes like
`new_tenants_path  GET  /tenants/new(.:format)tenants#new`
that is weird.
If I try `resource :tenant`, than the routes lose the `:id` because it will expect to be a singular resource.